# Showing indentations in Sphinx output

Tags: python, indentation, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I am trying to build a restructuredText file such that sphinx renders a hierarchy structure in html. How can I build the RST format to implement a printout like the following:

> This
>
> ```
>    Is
>
>       An 
>
>    Example
>
>        output
> ```

Answer (score 2):

`.. code-block:: text` where you manually indent the text is one option. If it is a file hierarchy, I like using [tree](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tree) to create the ASCII art diagram.

Nested lists are another. Note the [rules for nesting](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/rest.html#lists-and-quote-like-blocks).

> Nested lists are possible, but be aware that they must be separated from the parent list items by blank lines:

```
* This

  * Is

    * An 

  * Example

    * output
```

If you don't care for the bullets, you could use CSS to remove them.